# How to know when its running one or another flavor and set a specific code for each one?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to separate the code when I run the app. I have two flavours and one config.dart class for each flavour which have some variables and methods specific for each flavor.. How can I set one or another class when is one or another flavour running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dart define variables and parse inside your code.
https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/

```
flutter run --dart-define=FLAVOR=ALPHA
```

And parse in code like

```
var flavor = const String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR');
if (flavor == 'ALPHA'){
  // Set all your values
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the flavour name automatically? Instead of setting manually every run?

Comment: You can create multiple files for different flavor and run any one at a time something like this - https://github.com/enzoftware/flutter_flavors

Comment: I'm saying how to define this line : `flutter run --dart-define=FLAVOR= ?????` How to set the ???? dynamically with the current flavor

Comment: Ohh, I have no idea dear.

Comment: This is dangerous. It sets this in `ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` and then if you go to Xcode and build another target, it will load this same file and load the wrong config

Comment: @Karatekid430 please check the attached github repo https://github.com/mono0926/flutter-flavor-example/tree/develop/ios/Flutter
You need to create another xcconfig file and configure for specific flavor.

Comment: Yeah strangely that was the result I came to yesterday, but I am still stumped by Android. It is worrying that Google did not think this through too well.